# Default calibration file for Asus Xtion Pro Live?

Tags: ros, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Is there a default calibration file for the Asus Xtion Pro Live like the Kinect?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79146/default-calibration-file-for-asus-xtion-pro-live?/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2013-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it does have a default file because when launching the ASUS is says 'Using default parameters' like  below:

[ WARN] [1380795928.289543389]: Camera calibration file /home/ap/.ros/camera_info/rgb.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1380795928.289730843]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1380795928.289935967]: Camera calibration file /home/ap/.ros/camera_info/depth.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1380795928.290074043]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.

---

Originally posted by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) with karma: 42 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0